# How to get answers from solving system of equations in numerical form?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

So I am using sympy which gives me exact answers for system of equations but I would like to get the answers in numerical form and print them as that (for example 5931,023832). How can I do it?

My code is here:

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')
eq1 = sp.Eq((x - 5000)**2 + (y - 5000)**2, 2000**2)
eq2 = sp.Eq(((x-2500)/2000)**2 + ((y - 5000)/1000)**2, 1)
answer = sp.solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
print(answer[0], answer[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation via the `evalf` (or `n`) method will do this for you:

```
>>> [tuple([i.n(3) for i in j]) for j in answer]
[(3.23e+3, 4.07e+3), (3.23e+3, 5.93e+3), (8.44e+3, 5.0e+3 - 2.8e+3*I),
(8.44e+3, 5.0e+3 + 2.8e+3*I)]
```

The default is 15 digits of significance, but I chose 3 to make the results more compact.